# Grabbing data from database model and displaying it in a view won't show

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am porting a windows desktop application to an ASP.NET MVC application. I have a bunch of tables in the database that I am able to create controllers with to generate views and it works fine. I want to create a page to display all the names that have a certain column that is set to false. Because there is no table that stores this data I have to manually query for the result using linq. So what I have done is ignored the creation of the model and created the controller.

```
    private raceEntities db = new raceEntities();

    // GET: Registrants
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var registrants = (from per in db.people
                          join personorgrole in db.personorganizationroles on per.PersonID equals personorgrole.PersonID
                          join personeve in db.personevents on personorgrole.PersonOrganizationRoleID equals personeve.PersonOrganizationRoleID
                          join eventcla in db.eventclasses on personeve.RaceEventID equals eventcla.RaceEventID
                          join racecla in db.raceclasses on eventcla.RaceClassID equals racecla.RaceClassID
                          join personeventcla in db.personeventclasses on eventcla.EventClassID equals personeventcla.EventClassID
                          where personorgrole.PersonID == 90946
                          select new { per.FirstName, per.LastName }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Res = registrants;

        return View();
    }
```

and in the view i have this code

```
@model IEnumerable<IDFWebApp.Controllers.Custom.peopleController>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<ul>
    @foreach (var r in ViewBag.Res)
    {
        <li>
            @r
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Currently this query is for testing purposes to see if the data will show on the page, but it doesn't display the names.

Comment: Try simplifying the query, like return a simple array of names. That will show whether the problem is the query, the controller, or the view.

Comment: Also, you say, "it doesn't display the names". What _does_ it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on Karl's answer (anonymous types are internal and cant be accessed in the view), [this article](http://www.gregshackles.com/anonymous-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dynamics/) gives a good explanation of why it does not work

You need to create a view model

```
public class PersonVM
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And modify the GET method to

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var registrants = (from per in db.people
                      join personorgrole in db.personorganizationroles on per.PersonID equals personorgrole.PersonID
                      ....
                      where personorgrole.PersonID == 90946
                      select new PersonVM
                      {
                          FirstName = per.FirstName, 
                          LastName = per.LastName
                      }).ToList();
    return View(registrants);
}
```

And modify the view to

```
@model IEnumerable<yourAssembly.PersonVM>
<ul>
    @foreach (var person in Model)
    {
        // Assuming you want to display the FirstName and LastName properties
        <li><span>@person.LastName</span><span>@person.LastName</span></li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: hmmm this is really weird something seems to be wrong with my logic. I tested this out on a simpler query and it worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your `LINQ` projection is creating an anonymous type here:

```
select new { per.FirstName, per.LastName }
```

And while that is fine inside the controller, it is actually scoped as `internal`, which makes it inaccessible to the view. Thus your avoidance of using a server-side view model is making your `ViewBag` data unusable.

Make a server-side view model and pass it to the view. That is the standard approach to ASP.NET MVC development anyway.

Not saying the `ViewBag` is bad, but I would use it as a secondary approach instead of as a substitute to a view model.